# Change section format in memoir/latex

Tags: sectioning, memoir

[image]

The default format for section heading is `1.1` with memoir, how can I change it to `1.1.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the memoir manual 6.6 (p95):

```
\setsecnumformat{\csname the#1\endcsname.\quad}
```